# How to get a list of all binary numbers of length n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, permutation

I am trying to write some recursive python code which prints every binary number of length n. The input of the function should only be n. This is my code so far:

```
def printAll(n):
    result=[]
    stringSoFar=''
    def printAllrec(stringSoFar,n,result):
        if n ==0:
            result.append(stringSoFar)
            if len(result) == (2):
                return result
        else:
            printAllrec((stringSoFar+"0"),n-1,result)
            printAllrec((stringSoFar+"1"),n-1,result)

    return printAllrec(stringSoFar,n,result)
print(printAll(2))
```

However, this code keeps returning 'None'. I don't understand why it won't work. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't need more `return`s, it needs to return the right thing. `printAllrec` doesn't *use* return values here, it justs modifies a `list` provided to the top level `printAllrec` call, which is delegated to the child calls. But the top level function, `printAll`, needs to return that `list`, not the garbage return from the internal recursive function. Just change:

```
def printAll(n):
    ...

    return printAllrec(stringSoFar,n,result)
```

to:

```
def printAll(n):
    ...
    printAllrec(stringSoFar,n,result)
    return result  # returns the actual list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TaGgKDOvxDEnRyNP04pLAQiKUotLc0pso2PBvOISoHx6cL5bYpGtujpYCFlXUWqyBpISnTwdiHaoWSCQmaaQp2Bra4AQQdiil1hQkJqXgmyEJooyoOac1DwNqKFAYxQ0jDRRTYKYVlJalAc1FC6bmlOciqoW2dnIlmorGShp6uTpGsKcT6QuQzRdXOjKsYYNF6aTwXo04HFhpKn5/z8A)

and it works as expected.

Comment: @userj: Side-note: This needn't use either recursive solutions or imported modules. `def allbin(n): return [f'{i:0{n}b}' for i in range(1 << n)]` is enough to achieve the desired goal. The set of all bit strings of length `n` can be found by counting (the f-string is just formatting it to make it binary and pad with zeroes), which `range` does quite handily.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive generator could make the code much more compact. You just need to take every result from n-1 and append a "0" and a "1".

```
def allBits(n):
    if n: yield from ( bits+bit for bits in allBits(n-1) for bit in ("0","1") )
    else: yield ""

for bits in allBits(3):print(bits)

000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```